# Output from function 1 as input in function 2

Tags: python, function, pycharm

I am a newb at Python and have a question that I cant solve (a day and half).The first part of the question asks:

Create a function using a for loop that asks the user how many items and enter the items. The function should print it in a list.
**this works**

The second part of the question has be stumped. It asks: Write  another function that   takes   the list    that    you have    built   in  (a) as  input   and prints  the length
of  each    string  in  the list.   Finally print   the total   length  of  all strings.    You must    use a   for loop    in
your    program.

I have tried this but it prints out the output six times..

```
def gym(gymbag):
    y=int(input("How many items in your gym bag?"))
    gymbag=[]
    for x in range(y):
        f=input("Enter an item")
        gymbag.append(f)
    print(gymbag)

def gyms(gymbag):
    for i in range(len(gymbag)):
        len(gymbag)
        print(gymbag)
gym('gymbag')
gyms('gymbag')
```

Pls help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first function should have an output which can be given using `return`. You should use that output of the first function as input for the second function. Now you just passed a string as argument for your functions. Furthermore you didn't iterate through the items of the list. Something like this should work for you:

```
def gym():
    y=int(input("How many items in your gym bag?"))
    gymbag=[]
    for x in range(y):
        f=input("Enter an item")
        gymbag.append(f)
    print(gymbag)
    return gymbag

def gyms(gymbag):
    total_length = 0
    for item in gymbag:
        print(len(item)) # LENGTH OF ITEM
        total_length += len(item)
    print(total_length) # LENGHT OF ALL ITEMS COMBINED IN GYMBAG

gymbag = gym()
gyms(gymbag)
```

Comment: Thanks Justen, so I should use a boolean (total_length +=..) to add calculate length of each item?

Comment: A boolean is just True or False. It has nothing to do with this code. The total_length is an integer (number). What the function does is iterate through each item in gymbag and calculate the length of the item with len(item). The += is an assignment operator. It says that total_length is total_length PLUS the length of the new_item, effectively increasing total_length with the item length. By doing so for each item in the gymbag you end up with the total length of all strings combined in total_length

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fundamental idea of this exercise which is to return a value from the first function. Printing a value is not the same as returning it.

First, you should return the list `gymbag` from the `gym` function. Do that by adding the line
`return gymbag` after the print statement.

Then you have a problem with both the implementation and the usage of the `gyms` function. In order to iterate over a list and print the length of each string in it, you should iterate directly over the items and not on the number of items (you could do it that way, but you shouldn't most of the times):

```
for item in list_of_strings:
    print(len(item))
```

The problem in the usage is that you called it with a string and not a list of strings, and also it has nothing to do with the output of the `gymbag` function.

You can either do it directly, `gyms(gymbag())` or in 2 steps:

```
stuff = gym()
gymbag(stuff)
```

And lastly, function names are important. Try to give each function a the most descriptive name you can think of (within reasonable length).

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you chose python3 and I encourage you to keep on practicing to learn it even better.

Unfortunately, everything about your code is wrong. Firstly, the `gym` function has an input that is never used! You must never edit an argument before you have used it. Other mistakes are really trivial and like the one I mentioned. For instance, the `gymbag` list in the `gym` function is local, however you intend to use it like a global variable. You can do that alright (see [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)), but I recommend that you take the approach that @Justen chose. That is much more efficient and cleaner in general.